# External Variable in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, attributes

In Objective-C I used to have external variables using this statement:

```
extern int GlobalInt;
```

And it can be accessed and changed from any class without any restrictions.

**How can I produce such a variable in Swift 3.0?**

According to the answers it is very difficult to know the class that variable is declared on. Making everything mess up.

Is there any workaround to increase to make code clear and understandable for future modifications?

How do they replaced **atomicity, access, storage property attributes** from objective-C.

**Do they removed thus features or can we achieve these in swift?**

Comment: you don't need anything just do it with `var GlobalInt:Int`

Comment: how it will become external variable

Comment: check [here](http://railsware.com/blog/2014/06/11/global-variables-in-swift-are-not-variables/)

Comment: By Apple Magic.

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
var globalInt = 0
```

### Explanation

Extern is a construct in (Objective-)C to tell the compiler, that the variable is defined somewhere else (the data is somewhere else). Where is then resolved by the linker (last stage when creating an executable file).

You typically put `extern int GlobalInt` in `.h` file and then `int GlobalInt` in `.m` file.

In Swift you don't need that, because you don't have a separate header files. Just create a global variable.

If you are building a framework, you might need to add access modifier, like `public` to your definition.

Comment: It is very difficult to know the class where the variabales are used to declare. Any solution for making it readable

Comment: @Saranjith I don't quite understand your question, but I assume what you're saying is that only one class be able to configure this variable, and just be accessible from outside for reading. you can use `fileprivate(set)` as it's access level and only mutate this value in the file it's definied

Comment: does `extern` mean different file (in same library) or different library?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is just basically declare variable outside of any class scope...

```
var globalVar = 0


class MyClass{
//some declarations...
}
```

For better project structure, you can make some file containing global variables, like obviously `Globals.swift` and these variables store in there.

In there, you can set any properties you want, don't make any class, struct or whatever. This will serve you well as the global variables will be available throught your whole application. Problem with this approach is that it becomes messy and when you want to declare some variable inside class which by an accident has same identifier than the global one, you gonna have really bad time. For this cases, it is better to create some singleton object, which holds all the values for you. I would prefer singletons over global variables, since you know what are you looking for...

Generally, it is just better to avoid global variables as much as possible to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

For more Separation, You may add a new file for External variables only
like

```
/* This was previous code, instead of class use enum, because enum is not initialised
import Foundation

public class GlobalVariable{
    public static var gv_UserId:Int?
    public static var gv_UserName:String = "welcome"
    public static var gv_Password:String = "welcome"
}*/
```

Declare enum in any new file say Enum.swift, and paste the below code

```
enum GlobalVariableEnum: String {
    case userName = "welcome"
    case password = "welcome"
}
```

// now use this in required class like

```
let userName = GlobalVariableEnum.userName.rawValue
let password = GlobalVariableEnum.password.rawValue
```

Comment: This class doesn't guarantee it's uniqueness, so having multiple instances of GlobalVariable objects could occur. Consider the case you have instantiated GlobalVariable somewhere and forgotten and instantiated it elsewhere... Otherwise it could some other way refer to other instance as well..

Comment: @DominikBucher variables are static, so they're shared between all instances and do not loose their values

Comment: @farzadshbfn create 3 instances of the class and print the addresses of these variables and then write the same answer again

Comment: @DominikBucher  Why you will create instance of GlobalVariable class. assume Its just like a local database. You can get and set the value of these static variables and use them through out the project. When you create instance of this class, the goal or business logic to create this class also will be change.

Comment: @DominikBucher These two are two separate concepts. singleton is a design pattern (or maybe anti-pattern :/), but static variable, is part of the system and language. You don't access them through instance, you access them through class ex: `GlobalVariable.gv_UserId` not something like: `GlobalVariable.shared.gv_UserId`.

Comment: Don'T want to disappoint you but for these cases enum serves much better as namespace, classes or structs can be instantiated, which is really bad...

Comment: @ Dominik Bucher  Thanks for your advice :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make int variable in your AppDelegate Like

```
var globalInt = Int()
```

and where you are getting value of int send its value to AppDelegate. make AppDelgate object like below

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

to pass value to app delegate variable

```
self.appDelegate. globalInt = "your Value"
```

and get your values wherever you want to fetch like below

```
let  value = appDelegate. globalInt as! Int
```

values passed

and Update value anywhere you want by declaring app delegate object and writing following line

```
self.appDelegate. globalInt = "your Value"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a struct in your initial vc class before the class declaration like:

```
import UIKit

struct global {
   static var username: String="notset"
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
```

You can then use the global variable in any class in your project using the struct prefix. In this example:

```
global.username
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let string = MyVariables.yourVariable
println("Global variable:\(string)")
```

Changing value of variable:

```
MyVariables.yourVariable = "anotherString"
```